# downloading a branch from bazaar

Tags: bazaar

I am trying to download the calibre source code using Bazaar via the command:

```
bzr branch lp:calibre
```

In doing so, I get the message:

```
You have not informed bzr of your Launchpad ID, and you must do this to
write to Launchpad or access private data.  See "bzr help launchpad-login".
```

And then nothing.  I don't get an error message. It just keeps blinking and is stuck.

After a long time this is what is displayed:

```
Branched 12247 revisions.
```

But, if I go into the calibre folder it is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try to set you launchpad login ? `bzr launchpad-login YourLoginHere`

Comment: Please cd inside the directory and paste the output of this command: bzr status; bzr checkout .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it has created a branch without a working tree. If so, you should see a `.bzr` directory in the `calibre` directory. To create a working tree, run `bzr checkout` in the branch.

Answer (score 0):

The message you get about Launchpad ID is only a warning and you can ignore it for now.

It is normal that a branch operation takes long, keep in mind that it downloads the full history of the Calibre project.

The last message `Branched N revisions` indicates that the operation was successful. If you did this inside a *shared repository* that is configured with the `--no-trees` option then it is normal that the `calibre` directory contains only a `.bzr` directory, as in this configuration Bazaar will not create working trees. To create the working tree use the `bzr checkout .` command (notice the `.` (dot) at the end).

If you don't need the full history you can get the files much faster using so-called light-weight checkouts like this:

```
bzr checkout --light lp:calibre
```

Although this will speed up the branching process, all history operations like `bzr log` etc will take longer, as Bazaar will need to fetch data from Launchpad.